# How to remove extra left/right padding on AppCompatEditText inside ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-constraintlayout

I have an `AppCompatEditText` inside a `ConstraintLayout` and as always the line at the bottom of the `EditText` is indented a bit. I usually fix that by using a negative padding but the `ConstraintLayout` doesn't allow that, so how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing layout margins instead?
Plus could you also include some code as this will help determine problem.

As a side note:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatEditText.html

States:

> This will automatically be used when you use EditText in your layouts and the top-level activity / dialog is provided by appcompat. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views.

I only point this at as it annoys me when my colleagues do it.

Comment: Are saying change the margins of the outer layout to allow for the extra space? Yes I have done that before but it gets ugly. Let's say that I have 5 or 6 views one on top of the other and they all stretch the full width of the parent. The parent itself has a margin of `16dp`. I can remove the parent margin and put it on each view and then on the `EditText` I can just put `11dp` or whatever it needs to be to be aligned with the other views, but that is kind of ugly, isn't it?

Comment: I meant putting negative margins on the view (the AppCompatEditText) you were previously trying negative paddings on.

Comment: Also you could try setting bottom drawable of the EditText as a line in defined in xml drawable file, that should cover the full length of the EditText (set background as @null)

Comment: I didn't try negative margins, I'll see if the `ConstraintLayout` supports those. I can also try the line drawable, that might be the better solution in the end.

Comment: Setting a background with a "selector" drawable is how it is done (changes drawable based on focus, etc) normally. In this case each would be a slightly different line (colour, maybe thickness) set at the bottom, or if you wish it to remain the same independent of focus, just a straight drawable xml file will do. I would recommend putting up your xml file (sanitise the names/ ids) as it sounds like there should be an easier way of doing what you need (this usually means there is)